# Regex not matching double quotations in string (just single quotations)

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

I have written this regex to match translation strings. Everything works fine except it only matches single quotations `''` in strings, although I've written several rules to match both single and double quotations.

Here is my regex rule:

```
(Yii::t\()(\'|\")(.*?)(\'|\")\,(\'|\")(.*?)(\'|\")\)
```

as expected `(\'|\")` should match both ones but it doesn't.

I have also tried the following rules as well:

```
('|")
(['"])
```

Examples:

successfully matches these:

```
Yii::t('backend','My Profile')
Yii::t('backend','Log Out')
```

does not match these:

```
Yii::t("backend", "Search...")
Yii::t("backend", 'Sounds')
```

code i'm using to for matching regex:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(Yii::t\()(\'|\")(.*?)(\'|\")\,(\'|\")(.*?)(\'|\")\)`)
matches := re.FindAllString(line, -1)
```

**Update:
The problem was because some strings contained white spaces (not because of quotations).**

Comment: Can you provide some test input strings?

Comment: @Gurman The input strings are from PHP codes. It searches project and looks for match in the code. I have updated the question with some examples by the way.

Comment: And to be sure, would you please post your assign statement like `patther := "..."`?

Comment: It doesn't match because of the extra space! Otherwise it matches! I checked it on regex101.com. [see here](https://regex101.com/r/pz1Ce1/2)

Comment: @csabinho Oh. I guess that's the case. Can you provide regex to match spaces (if exists) in answer please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
Yii::t\((?:['"][^'"]*['"],?\s*)*\)
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wDVP68/2)

**Explanation:**

- `Yii::t\(` - matches `Yii::t(` literally
- `(?:['"][^'"]+['"],?\s*)*\)`

  - `['"]` - matches either `'` or `"`
  - `[^'"]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither `'` nor `"`
  - `['"]` - matches a single occurrence of either `'` or `"`
  - `,?` - matches 0 or 1 occurrence of a `,`
  - `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace
  - `*` - The last `*` matches the above 5 sub-patterns 0+ times
  - `\)` - matches `)` literally

**Alternative Solution:**

[`Yii::t\(\s*['"][^'"]*['"]\s*(?:,\s*['"][^'"]*['"]\s*)*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/wDVP68/3)

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation. I guess adding `\s*` in the places that may contain white space may do the trick as well.

Comment: @sobhanbagheri I have tried to include that in my alternative solution as shown [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/wDVP68/4)

Comment: Alternative regex had a little problem which caused some illegal strings (not translates) match and capture. I guess this is a better one (the non capturing group has been removed):

`Yii::t\(\s*['"][^'"]*['"]\s*\,\s*['"][^'"]*['"]\s*\)`

Comment: It's OK if it suits your requirements. :)

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx matches everything:

```
(Yii::t\(\s*)(\'|\")(.*?)(\'|\")\,\s*(\'|\")(.*?)(\'|\")\)
```

[See here](https://regex101.com/r/pz1Ce1/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex , This matches everything :

```
Yii::t\(('|")(.*)(\'|\"),('|[  ]("|'))(.*)('|")\)
```

[Click here for output !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACtzq.png)